Getting monthly and then yearly average for LST MODIS raster data
I am using MODIS LST products to get the monthly and then the yearly average for the year 2002. But, I am get NULL value for the getZ function, however the setZ function works correctly.
files<- list.files(pattern = ".tif", full.names = F)
s<-stack()

# loop over 8-day files for the year 2002
for (file in files) { 
  jdt<-as.numeric(substr(file,34,36))
  jdt <- as.numeric(jdt-1) # R uses a 0 based index for dates only # this means it starts counting at 0 rather than 1 when working with dates
  year<-as.numeric(substr(file,30,33))
  mydate<- as.Date(jdt, origin = as.Date(as.character(paste(year,"-01","-01", sep=""),format="%Y%m%d")))
  r<-raster(file)
  ras <- setZ(r, mydate,'time') # attach date to respective raster
  s<-stack(s,ras)
  print(getZ(s)) # Returns NULL
  month_avg <- stackApply(s, months(getZ(s)), fun = mean)
  year_avg <- calc(month_avg, fun = mean)
  writeRaster(year_avg,filename = paste("mean_lst_night_", year, ".tif", sep = ""), format = "GTiff")
}

I don't quite understand what is wrong here. I'd really appreciate any help.
